# Uber Central API

Tags: uber-api

Trying to find concrete information regarding whether or not you can request rides for other people using an Uber Central API. I want to be able to offer clients that come to my business a ride home or a ride to my business. I see Uber Central is meant to fill that, but is there a way to use the API to do what Uber Central is made to do?

Specifically, is there an Uber Central API available yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm there is not an Uber Central API available.

Comment: I've noticed something else called Uber Health, which is stated to have an API. Are you aware if this API available to be used currently?

Comment: There is not any publicly available Uber Health API at the moment. Based on what you are looking for, the Uber Central dashboard sounds like the closest to what you want.